# How to view Atom's console in a separate window?

Tags: console, atom-editor

I am running Atom (version 1.25.1 x64) on Mac.

Atom's Console, by default, appears at the bottom of the window that the editor occupies.

Is it possible to "pop out" the Console, so that it has its own dedicated, discrete window?

I ultimately want to move this Console window to an adjacent display, as the bottom panel is simply too narrow for me to work efficiently in certain instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a "popped-out" console window in Atom is *no different* than just opening up the Terminal app on a Mac and running your app or commands there, side-by-side with your Atom window. You'll literally have an entirely "dedicated" and separate console window.

But if you really want to do everything *within* Atom, try using the [platformio-ide-terminal](https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal) package.

1. Install [platformio-ide-terminal](https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal)
2. From your main Atom window, open a new window (shift + cmd + N)
3. On the new window, open a new terminal (i.e. click the `+` at the bottom panel)
4. Toggle the terminal panel to fullscreen (i.e. click the fullscreen/maximize button)

Which will give you something like this:

[image: sample with 2 windows]

You can then move that "console window" to another adjacent display.

Still, as I said, it might be better to just use the Terminal app.

Comment: Great answer to the question.  One use case I have for staying inside Atom, rather than using the Terminal app (I use both) is using [ruby test](https://atom.io/packages/ruby-test) to run specs while remaining within the context of writing/editing specs.